# Symbology in QGIS for plan drawing regulation in Germany

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, germany

In Germany we have to use standardized symbols for maps of the land use planning ("Bauleitplanung", "Bebauungspläne", "Flächennutzungsplane").

These symbols are defined in an act called "Planzeichenverordnung".

Here are some examples of the defined symbols for polygons

[image: example1]

and for points.

[image: example2]

All symbols are [listed here](http://www.dr-frank-schroeter.de/planzv.htm#Anlage).

How can I use these symbols in QGIS? Are there any predefined symbol sets which I can use?

---

Original question was in German (Translated by @Jens):

Gibt es für QGIS eine Phytonerweiterung "Planzeichenverordnung"? Zur Bearbeitung von Flächennutzungsplänen und Bebauungsplänen kommt man an den Planzeichen nicht herum.

Comment: You don't need a python-plugin, you just need the icon set. Just use the image program of your choice and recreate them (they don't look that hard)

Answer (score 1):

If suddenly someone is still looking for a solution after 7 years.

Go to this web site: https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/planzv_90/BJNR000580991.html

And choose the symbol you need and afterwards simply `'Save Image As...'`

[image: example]

Then in QGIS for a single point symbol use `'Filled marker > Fill > Raster image fill'`, see image below.

[image: example]

The output will be looking something like this

[image: result]

As an alternative you can try following the workflow provided in this thread [Import PNG symbols in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189980/import-png-symbols-in-qgis) to convert your your `JPG` into something vectorized.

---

**References:**

- [Verordnung über die Ausarbeitung der Bauleitpläne und die Darstellung des Planinhalts (Planzeichenverordnung - PlanZV)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/planzv_90/BJNR000580991.html)